# Differentiating fraction $\phi(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{(1+\theta^2)}.$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I graduate high school many years ago, and I have no idea where to find how to differentiate this formulae.

$$\phi(\theta) = \frac{\theta}{(1+\theta^2)}.$$

I have a solution of it, but I know not how.

$$\frac{d}{d\theta} \phi(\theta) = \frac{(1-\theta^2)}{(1+\theta^2)}$$

Could you let me know how to solve this one? Fortunately, I know how to differentiate the other kind of formula.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To deal with differentiation of quotients, you can use the quotient rule:
$$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\frac{f(\theta)}{g(\theta)}\right) = \frac{g(\theta)f'(\theta) - g'(\theta)f(\theta)}{(g(\theta))^2}$$
In this case, you have $f(\theta) = \theta$ and $g(\theta) = 1 + \theta^2$. Then $\frac{d}{d\theta}f(\theta) = 1$ and $\frac{d}{d\theta}g(\theta) = 2\theta$, so plugging in: $$
\frac{d}{d\theta}\phi(\theta) = \frac{(1+\theta^2)(1) - (\theta)(2\theta)}{(1+\theta^2)^2} = \frac{1-\theta^2}{(1+\theta^2)^2}.$$

Comment: Dear @amras1, 
This is what I want to find. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Use the quotient rule. The answer you give is incorrect, however. The denominator of $\phi'$ is $(1 + \theta^2)^2$.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Now I understand it from the others answers. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Another way: if $\varphi( \cdot )$ is the function, then define $L \varphi = \log \varphi(\cdot)$, and in your case 
$$
L \varphi = \log \theta - \log (1 +\theta^2)
$$
Now differentiate both sides; remember $(\log \varphi( x))_{x}' = \frac{\varphi'(x
)}{\varphi(x)}$.

Can you handle from here?

Comment: What about $\theta < 0$?

Comment: I honestly don't know; of course $\log$ function is undefined for $x < 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but since the OP didn't provide the support of $\theta$, I don't see why this method of differentiation doesn't apply

Comment: That is the drawback of logarithmic differentiation. You have to pay close attention to the range. The answer, BTW, is to differentiate $-\phi$ on the set where $\phi < 0$ and multiply the result by $-1$.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Quotient rule is:
$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\theta} \dfrac{g(\theta)}{f(\theta)}= \dfrac{f(\theta)g'(\theta)-f'(\theta)g(\theta)}{f(\theta)^2}$

Here $g(\theta)=\theta \implies g'(\theta)= 1$

And $f(\theta)=1+\theta^2\implies f'(\theta)=2\theta$